# sass: import + extend inside of class

Tags: sass

I have code that imports 2 different sass files, each file have a class with the same name.  E.g.

**a.sass**:

```
%test
  background-color: aqua
```

**b.sass**:

```
%test
  background-color: blue
```

**c.sass**:

```
.aqua
  @import "a"
  @extend %test

.blue
  @import "b"
  @extend %test
```

Now compiling it::`sass c.sass` and I get:

```
.aqua .aqua, .aqua .blue {
  background-color: aqua; }

.blue .aqua, .blue .blue {
  background-color: blue; }
```

How do I make it work properly, I want:

```
.aqua {
  background-color: aqua; }

.blue {
  background-color: blue; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the import outside the class definition. Otherwise the imported rules will be appended to the current selector too.

```
@import "a"
.aqua
  @extend %test

@import "b"
.blue
  @extend %test
```

Comment: Doesn't this expose imports to the global scope?

Comment: @deathangel908 yes, but otherwise it will act like the selector is extending itself and will duplicate the selector

Comment: it produces `.aqua, .blue {   background-color: aqua; }`  + `.aqua, .blue { background-color: blue; }`. Is there any way to compile it into result I wrote in the question?

Comment: @deathangel908 the problem if that both are exposed globally, they will extend each other. Why not changing the extend name?

Comment: 3rd party libs ;(

Comment: @deathangel908 i dont know if this has a solution